# How to initialize a variable periodically in c

Tags: c

I am trying to implement a token bucket algo where I want to initialize my tokens every time in every x seconds with t tokens. Let say in every 5 seconds I want  to initialize the tokens with 10. If 5 seconds are over then reinitialize my tokens again with 10.

```
while(1) 
{
 if(/* 5 seconds are over, reinitialize the tokens with 10 */)  
 /* Initialize a variable */
 token = 10;   /*  tokens are 5 */
 else
 token --;
}
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Does your loop do anything else? If not, it will hog your CPU, and the value of `token` will loop and reach 10 again many times per second.

Comment: You need to state your environment. What kind of time tracking is available? Does your OS provide? Does your (microcontroller) hardware provide?

Answer (score 0):

assuming you're on windows you might want to consider such solution:

```
  uint32_t token;
  time_t tokenInitialization;
  time_t check;
  token = 10;
  time(&tokenInitialization);
  while (1)
  {
    Sleep(1000);
    time(&check);
    if (difftime(check,tokenInitialization) >= 5)
    {
      printf("reinitializing.. %d\n",token);
      time(&tokenInitialization);
      /* 5 seconds are over, reinitialize the tokens with 10 */
      /* Initialize a variable */
      token = 10;   /*  tokens are 5 */
    }
    else
      token--;
  }
```

Comment: Your while-loop is never going to end!

Comment: OPs question was about how to "initialize a variable periodically in c". Thread termination check should be included correct, but he gave no info about his enviroment, nor given whole code.

Answer (score 0):

On an unix system you can use the alarm system. On this sample code the token is a  global variable. For portability probably solutions which use functions to get the time are worth a look. I show here a possible solution with the alarm mechanism.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

void reset_token(int);
int token;

int main () {
    // Sets SIGALARM to be delivered to this process in 5 seconds
    alarm(5);

    // Sets our reset_token to be called each time
    // a SIGALARM is received
    signal(SIGALARM, reset_token);

    token=10;

    while(1) {
        token--;
    }

    return(0);
}

void reset_token(int signum) {
    // This function is called every time this process
    // receives a SIGALARM. We reset the token here.

    token=10;

    // Sets SIGALARM to be delivered again in 5 seconds
    alarm(5);
}
```

Comment: There are better solutions. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**It is operating system specific.** If you run without an OS, it is platform and hardware specific.

### For Linux and POSIX

For Linux read also [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) and consider perhaps [timer_create(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html) and related functions. [alarm(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/alarm.2.html) is old-fashion (and have a one second granularity; other system calls enable much smaller timer intervals, perhaps less than a millisecond).

**Don't use busy waiting loops:** they run CPU cycles uselessly (so consume power and heat your processor and suck your laptop battery). Use some idle loop to wait. You could use [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) in some event loop, or use [pause(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pause.2.html), [nanosleep(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html), etc...

Be sure to read [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html). If you have a signal handler, set some `volatile sig_atomic_t`  flag in it that you would test elsewhere.

---

Read about [volatile variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_(computer_programming)). You surely need to use some (even on other platforms). Very probably your `token` variable should be [`volatile`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/volatile). With C11, consider perhaps also [atomic operations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic).

---

You could also consider some multi-[threaded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)) approach. Read some [Pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) and do care about [synchronization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_(computer_science)), [atomicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability), [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)-ity, [mutexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)), [semaphores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)).